# make DIV 100% width when scrollbar is @ bottom with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a width DIV grow to 100% when the scrollbar is at the bottom, 
and shrink to 0% when the scrollbar is at the top of the page.

I tried to make it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {



       var myWidth = $(window).width();
       var res = myWidth / 100;


       var myHeight = $(document).height();


       var myScreen = $(window).height();


       $(window).scroll(function () {

           var scrolling = $(window).scrollTop();

           var myPrecentage = (scrolling + myScreen) / (myHeight );

           console.log(myPrecentage);
           $('#com1').css("width", ((myPrecentage) * 100) + "%");



       });

   });
```

I came across a problem, when I try to use the scrollTop, it doesnt calculate the screen height, so I alwayes start when the scrollTop is 0, about 20% of width.

have you got better idea how to tackle it ?

Comment: What is happening with your current code? You said the screen height isn't calculating correctly, what value are you getting and what are you expecting? Given the incorrect screen size value, does the rest of the code work? Are you looking for a different implementation? Your logic looks sound, I'm curious what issue you're experiencing.

Comment: the hight of my page for example is : 2133px, and my scrollTop when its at the bottom is 1789px.   I am 344px short, which is basically, my screen height.

Comment: so my "var precentage" is 0.16736990154711673 px when I begin to scroll, because its adding the screen height...  I need somehow to make it 0 when its at the top, and add it (graduatlly) when its at the bottom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not have fully understood what you are trying to do, but it sounds like you want to compute % between 0 and 100% based on where you are in your scroll. (Perhaps you want to translate vertical action to horizontal graph representation.)

Your code works, and just needs minor adjustment. Right now you are computing % based on:

`var myPrecentage = (scrolling + myScreen) / (myHeight );`

What you want is:

`var myPrecentage = scrolling / (myHeight - myScreen);`

Which is same as:

`$(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height());`

(I should add, I'm using Chrome - behavior may differ across browsers.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your current problem is that you're always starting off with the size of the view window. So unless the view is at 0, you'll always start with a < zero number. You only want to add scrolling and myScreen when the scrolling view has passed beyond the myScreen size.

http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/C2aFH/

```
var myPrecentage;
if((scrolling - myScreen) < myScreen){
       myPrecentage = (scrolling) / (myHeight );               
} else {
       myPrecentage = (scrolling + myScreen) / (myHeight );
}
```